# Amazon Message Queue Service (SQS) sending and confirmation

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs

**Scenario:**

A elastic beanstalk environment has a few web servers which sends a request to another worker environment for user sign up, etc.

**Problem:**

When one of the worker machines have finished the task, I also want it to send a confirmation to the web server.

It seems that SQS does not have "confirmation" message.

When we offload a job to send a email, but I also want to let the web server to know that send email was successful.

One solution I could do is implement another queue that the web server polls, however, many servers can poll on the same queue, and the confirmation for  **Server 1**, can be recieved by **Server 2**, and we would need to wait for a **timeout** for the message, but then **Server 3** might intercept the message. It could wait a while for **Server 1** to get a confirmation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way your worker machines "confirm" they processed a message is by deleting it from the queue. The lifecycle of a queue message is:

1. Web server sends a message with a request.
2. Worker receives the message.
3. Worker processes the message successfully.
4. Worker deletes the message.

A message being deleted is the confirmation that it was processed successfully.

If the worker does not delete the message in step 4 then the message will reappear in the queue after a specified timeout, and the next worker to check for messages will get it and process it.

If you are concerned that a message might be impossible to process and keep reappearing in the queue forever, you can set up a "dead letter" queue. After a message has been received a specified number of times but never deleted, the message is transferred to the dead letter queue, where you can have a process for dealing with these unusual situations.

Amazon's Simple Queue Service [Developer Guide](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/Welcome.html) has a good, clear explanation of this lifecycle and how you can be sure that every message is processed or moved to a dead letter queue for special handling.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed reply. Does it mean that the web server also needs to poll to see if the message still remains? If it disappears, then it is confirmed that the task had succeeded? Does this added wait time justify the worthiness of a decoupled system? Since it could be easier if the web server does all the email sending, etc.

Comment: If the message disappears, that does confirm that it was processed successfully. As for whether the web server needs to poll, well, it depends on the use case. Why does the web server need to know this? What will it do upon discovering success or failure? From what I understand of your description, the web server just needs to send an email, so why does it bother with confirmation? Once you put the message in the queue, you can be confident that it will cause an email to sent if it's possible. If it's not possible the message will eventually end up in the dead letter queue for manual handling.

Comment: If you want the web server to wait for the email to be sent before responding to a web request, then there's no reason to use a message queue. Just send the email from the web server as part of responding to a request. The benefit of a message queue is that you can request an operation to happen asynchronously and immediately go on to the next thing without waiting.

Comment: If the web server knows that the message is sent, then it could also notify the user on the same page if possible. I wrote my back-end in Java, but I'm deciding to use Python for my front-end. It seems easier to use SQS for communication.

Comment: If the process that wants the email sent wants to wait for the result, it shouldn't use a message queue. It should send the email itself, or use something like a web service to do it instead. Message queues are for when you want something done but don't want to wait for it to complete.